# How to add form field values using javascript and/or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, sum

Hi I have a form and a script and it works great to add and multiply values in a form i made...only problem is it wont add decimal numbers.  Any way to fix this?

```
<form>

<input type="text" id="1" name="1" >
<input type="text" id="2" name="2" value="1.11">
<input type="text" id="A" name="A">
<input type="text" id="B" name="B">
<input type="text" id="total" name="total">

<button type="button" id="calculate" name="button">Calculate</button>

</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calculate').on('click',function(){
        var v1 =  $('#1').val();  // take first text box value
        var v2 =  $('#2').val();  // take second hidden text box value
        $('#A').val(parseInt(v1)+parseInt(v2)); // set value of A
        var aval = (parseInt($('#A').val()) * parseFloat(.08)); // calculate value of b
        $('#B').val(aval);// set value of B
        var totalval = parseInt($('#A').val()) + parseFloat(aval);
        //calculate value for total
        $("#total").val(totalval); // set total
    })

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1s3hoeqw/2/

Comment: instead of `parseInt` use `parseFloat`

Comment: which parse int do i change?

Comment: use parseFloat all fields

Comment: changed all parseInt to parseFloat...dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make some changes in your jsfiddle example....please take a look at it....it's working as you want

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/1s3hoeqw/11/`
```

well, using parseInt instead of parseFloat was causing errors in calculations...but now I have updated above link...please take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

convert string to number using `+ operator`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calculate').on('click', function () {
        var v1 = $('#1').val(); // take first text box value
        var v2 = $('#2').val(); // take second hidden text box value
        $('#A').val((+v1) + (+v2)); // set value of A
        var aval = $('#A').val() * .8; // calculate value of b
        $('#B').val(aval); // set value of B
        var totalval = (+$('#A').val()) + aval;
        //calculate value for total
        $("#total").val(totalval); // set total
    })

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1s3hoeqw/4/)**

Comment: nice any way to make the total in dollar amount format ex. 0.00

Comment: @MarkRodriguez use  $("#total").val(parseFloat(totalval)); // set total

Comment: @MarkRodriguez or use toFixed() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: thanks pal... any way to make the total in two decimal number format example: 0.00